# QCompleter - Tree Model Unique Items

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to create a solution for a custom `QCompleter` that only returns one selection choice when there are multiple rows with the same value, however there may be different children.

In the picture bellow there is an example of a tree (formatted wrong), where there are two rows with the same name *"Parent1"*. As you can see at the bottom of the image this return two entries for each row. I would like to only return one option however on the next search term "Parent1.Ch" for the options to be returned for both rows.
[image: Example]

I have tried to implement a `QSortFilterProxyModel` to only return a row if another row with the same text hasn't been shown already:

```
bool UniqueFilterProxyModel::filterAcceptsRow(int sourceRow, const QModelIndex &sourceParent) const

    {
        QModelIndex index = sourceModel()->index(sourceRow, filterKeyColumn(), sourceParent);
    
        if(!(m_list.contains(index.data().toString()))) {
    
            const_cast<UniqueFilterProxyModel *>(this)->m_list.append(index.data().toString());
            return true;
        }
        else
        return false;
    }
```

However this this doesn't solve the problem as `QCompleter` will still only search the children of the row that is valid. I'm a bit stuck on how to correct this issue without creating a separate model.

Answer (score 0):

Based on code provided, which is very limited, I would check that the method contains() does exactly what is expected. Or, provide more implementation details.